# XPath required for text without HTML tag

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML Markup:

```
<div>
<strong>Property type:</strong>  Apartments<br>
<strong>Typology:</strong>  T2<br>
<strong>Living area</strong>  61 m² <br>
<strong>Total area</strong>  61 m²<br>
<strong>Construction year:</strong>  2007                           </div>
```

**I'd like to target `2007` although I'm coming up short on the syntax**. I can target `Construction year:` with the following XPath but can't quite figure out the rest:

```
//strong[ contains( text(), "Construction year:" ) ]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//strong[ contains( text(), "Construction year:" ) ]/following-sibling::text()[1]`

Comment: Hey @Forensic_07 - Thanks so much for chiming in  I've added more of the markup in an edit. When using either of the syntaxes you shared, I'm getting *all* of the text and not just the `2007` part - What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, that changes the situation. Updating answer.

Comment: Oh wow! Completely forgot about `/following-sibling` --> Thanks so much!!